# How do I remove Xen from Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xen

I was trying to install VM software on my Ubuntu system. Since I'm not very familiar with linux I followed [**a guide**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen) on the official Ubuntu site. Now I am running Ubuntu in a Xen environment, but I don't want to use Xen to make my virtual machines.

I installed Virtualbox in order to create my VM's, but Virtualbox doesn't run in a Xen environment.

I have tried googling for a way to remove Xen from my system, but I am unable to do it. This is what I've tried so far:

- Editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` `set default="Xen 4.1-amd64"` to set `default=1` which was recommended by a tutorial. It made my laptop start up in recovery mode and I had to generate a new grub config file which put the default back to xen.
- Editing `/boot/grub/menu.lst` but I don't have any files called that on my system

> user@BEL-8WF4XW1:~$ sudo find / -name menu.lst
>
> user@BEL-8WF4XW1:~$

- Looking through software center, but I couldn't find anything about Xen
- The command `make uninstall` but I didn't use the source code.
- I also tried to install `yum` and do `sudo yum install kernel` followed by `sudo yum remove xen kernel-xen libvirt` but that also didn't work.

I'm quite lost to be honest. Can anyone help me to get my Ubuntu back to how it was before I tried to follow that guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just try

`sudo apt-get remove xen-hypervisor-amd64`

or

`dpkg -i xen-hypervisor-amd64`

to see which xen files have been installed in your machine

Comment: This did not work for me. apt says: Note, selecting 'xen-hypervisor-4.9-amd64' instead of 'xen-hypervisor-amd64'
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 23 not to upgrade.
autoclean gets rid of some files, but only the apt purge command bellow got rid of xen from my system.

Answer (score 10):

I'm no expert but I've executed

```
sudo apt-get purge xen*
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: This also worked for me when "sudo apt remove xen-hypervisor-amd64" did not.